# Motor shields in arduino

Tags: servo, arduino-motor-shield

what is a servo motor shield in arduino? what is the key purpose for using it? I'm newbie in arduino and I've seen some briefings in websites which I couldn't understand, can somebody elaborate it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Servos require power and PWM. Servo shields come in two main forms:

1. Simple distribution
2. Active control

The first kind just provides convenient 3-pin headers to the Ardino's PWM pins, and sometimes a dedicated power supply for powering the servos. They're simple and cheap, but can only provide as many servo ports as the Arduino has PWM pins.

[The second kind](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1411), more expensive, has a PWM chip on it to provide many more PWM pins than the Arduino can natively provide. Again there is sometimes a power supply as well, along with the convenient 3-pin headers. You usually interface with this kind using either I2C or SPI.  These are the ones people usually mean when they talk about a servo shield - a shield designed for powering and controlling many more servos than an Arduino by itself can manage.

Servo Motor Shields should not be confused with Motor Shields, which provide a number of H-Bridge drivers for powering and controlling (both the speed and direction) of a brushed DC motor.

Answer (score -1):

The dumb ones are basically distributors of power for the servo motors.
There are more clever boards that offer the control of multiple servos (usually 10+) by communicating with the Arduino via some higher-than-PWM-level control (Like I2C) thus taking less pins from the Arduino than a dumb servo shield.
Both kinds usually require a power supply to power the servos.

G.

Comment: He said "servo motor shield", not a DC motor driving shield. Very different thing.

Comment: do you mean that using motor shields provides external power to servo?

Comment: @Majenko How does my answer suggest I am talking about a DC motor shield? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: "So, you need something that takes the signal from these pins and translate them into high current controls." - that is what a DC motor shield does. It's not what a servo motor shield does. You have perfectly described a H-bridge shield.

Comment: @Dharanendiran Almost. A motor shield provides power to the servo/stepper motor but that power has to tome from somewhere, so to make a motor shield work you'll need a power supply to power the shield itself and you may need another power supply to power your Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko It is what ALL motor shields do, that's why you need them: to be able to handle high currents. (higher than what the Arduino pins can handle) What you hook up to the other end of the shield is not specified in that sentence, it can be a stepper motor or a servo motor or a DC motor.

Comment: @KillerRabbitofCaerbannog Do you actually know how a servo motor works, and what signals it requires?

Comment: Yes I do, and let me Google it: http://www.jameco.com/jameco/workshop/howitworks/how-servo-motors-work.html
Sorry, sent it a bit early, I'll elaborate

Comment: Ok, so if you know how a servo motor works - tell me: *what* signal(s) would you possibly want to amplify using a H-bridge?

Comment: I see why you think I was talking about DC motors. Most servos contain their electronics, so you only need high current DC supply for them and a signal with PWM. A servo shield gives it power and takes the incoming signal and sends it to the motor. (or even buffers it but that's another topic) I made a mistake with the amplifying thing as I did not state explicitly that you only amplify (or more like translate) signals with stepper motors.

Comment: You need a motor shield for stepper or DC motors. Not for servo motors. You can directly drive as many servo motors direct from an Arduino as there are PWM pins (and more if you implement software PWM). There is no need for any amplification or buffering unless you are using long runs of cable and need the extra current to get the signal there cleanly. Your answer doesn't mention a single thing that is relevant to servo motors, and the OP didn't ask about DC or stepper motors.

Comment: @Majenko You can directly CONTROL as many servo motors direct from an Arduino as there are PWM pins. You still need some kind of power distribution to the servos, and that's what a "servo motor shield" does. Also, as you said, you don't need a motor shield for servo motors. Then the author was maybe talking about "servo motor control". Or he/she did talk about "motor shield". I elaborated the latter extending it to stepper motors. I am sorry if my answer was ambiguous and hope that the author wanted to know about steppers too.

Comment: That is what ***one*** kind of servo motor shield does. Those are cheap and rare (and often just a part of another bigger shield). The most common kind of servo motor shield also contain a PWM chip (like I linked to in my answer) for generating more PWM signals than the Arduino can create. THAT is what a servo motor shield is for. The power distribution is just a bonus. It's just as easy to use wires to distribute the power.

Comment: You should remove all references to H-bridges, amplifying of signals, DC motor / stepper motor driving, etc from your answer as they are nothing to do with the question and are just plain misleading.

Comment: @Majenko "and often just a part of another bigger shield" And that's why I wandered into stepper territory. Most motor shields provide stepper, DC and servo control which makes it appropriate to talk about all of these motors hence the "amplifying" stuff in my answer. My error was not stating that, I'll correct my answer later today.

Comment: SOME DC motor shields also provide handy servo pins since you often want to use servos and DC motors together (drive & steering). However, a servo motor shield (which is what the OP asked about) NEVER has DC motor driving capability.

Comment: I understand how you find my answer misleading and I'll rewrite it to make sure it is not anymore.